# What does logging actually do on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, logging

I see code like this in Android samples all the time?

```
try { ... }
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
}
```

What does `Log.e` actually do on a physical device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes to the system log, which devs can access through the SDK tools, through `adb logcat` or which you can access with apps like aLogcat. Debug log statements are generally removed by Android's default app release build process.

Comment: Is there anyway a user can send me the `Log.e` information from the device using just the OS tools?  Or is this something that I'd need to build into the app?

Comment: Have them download aLogcat and use that to send you logs. There is no way you could otherwise read their logs, short of requesting app permission to read the whole system log and send it back to you, and that's very sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Log prints the line out to the system's console log which you can dump in real time using the `adb` tool. E.g.: `adb logcat`. Or you can view it using the Eclipse-based debug tools.

My favorite log flavor is [Log.wtf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

The device keeps a rolling log called the logcat.  This can be read across ADB by several IDE or stand alone tools in the android SDK.  Used this way it is a good debugging tool.

On a device the logcat can be sent for remote debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`Log.e` specifically is used to log errors but Log in general is used for all kinds of logging (errors, warnings, debug, verbose, etc). These are very helpful for debugging an application. Here, is a very good tutorial explaining this - [Application Logging](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/logcat_android-sdk/)

Hope this helps.